# Is it ok to place "better" like this?

Tags: adjective-position

Can these two sentence be considered as having the same meaning? Also, is there any grammatical error in the latter one?

> Because he's keeping an eye on his dark side, he's better able to keep it in check.

> Because he's keeping an eye on his dark side, he's able to keep it in check better.

Comment: _Better able (to)_ is something of a fixed phrase, since it makes people able to better avoid splitting infinitives, if that's their thing.

Comment: See also: [Better able to or able to better](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/331412/50044)

Answer (score 2):

They are both grammatical. We tend to put *better* in the first position with short complements and the second position with long complements, so English speakers would tend not to use the starred sentences in the pairs below.

> *With his new, expensive shoes, he's better able to run.
> With his new, expensive shoes, he's able to run better.
>
> With the reorganization, we are better able to respond to climate change and pursue sustainable development.
> *With the reorganization, we are able to respond to climate change and pursue sustainable development better.

For your sentence, with an intermediate-length complement, both positions sound fine to me.